# Are Nodejs modules portable across different Linux distributions?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, npm

As far as I know some node.js modules rely on native OS libraries support, like node-imagimagick.

But this question bothers me for a while.

Say in one Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) I've got a nodejs app, with all dependency downloaded via `npm install`, can the nodejs app along with the dependency be simply copied to another OS (different linux distribution, e.g. Redhat) and run smoothly, assuming the latter one has required native libraries.

Will there be any compatibility issue?

I think the real questions is what does `npm install` do? does it build OS specific binary code or just download the javascript libraries.

Comment: `npm install` retrieves modules from [npmjs.org](http://npmjs.org) as they are published there by the module authors. So you can't really make a general statement about all modules.

Answer (score 0):

Like the imagemagick example, certain npm modules may have dependencies that are external to the application. For example, a ZeroMQ npm module would not include a ZeroMQ binary (or should not).

If you want complete portability between Linux distributions you can consider using Docker containers. You could, for example, have your Dockerfile satisfy all the prerequisite (e.g. install ZeroMQ) and then have your node app run inside of that container. This way you can be sure that all the npm modules you are using will work as they have worked on your linux distro.

Comment: Thanks. Actually we are using docker container, we've got Dockerfile do env configuration, and npm install as well.  But still, I"m curious whether the node_modules are portable given the target env has binary deps installed?

Comment: Then the answer would be no, they are not. As laggingreflex had mentioned, npm modules are published by arbitrary developers and may include third party binary dependencies that are not pre-installed on all linux distros.

Comment: So npm install do something like `make`? Could you name one example?

Comment: There may be similarities with make, depends what your Makefile does. But I find it more like apt-get. As for an example. Consider this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/zeromq
If you include this npm module as a dependency in your package.json file, your app might work well on your machine (if you installed ZMQ before), but when your fellow developer fetches your code from git, and that developer did not previously installed ZMQ, when he/she runs npm install, they will encounter an error (either when npm installing or worse - when running the app).

Comment: As I mentioned in my question and my response, the server has every third-party libraries needed installed, will the node_module copied to this server works fine?